Login via SQLServer AlwaysOn "Listener" Failed (Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5)
I have setup an AlwaysOn Availability Group on SQLServer 2022.
I have created a login on both replicas with same SID. 
But I could not login via listener IP or DomainName via SSMS.
I could login separately on each replica (Primary/Secondary) but not by Listener!!
The odd fact is that I have done this before many times on other servers and even on same SQL Server version (2022).
There is only two differences, I checked the contained option on this AG & the CU here is a bit newer than the other servers where I used SQL Server 2022 (CU12 - KB5033663, May 2024)
Error inside SQL Server error log:
Login failed for user "..." . Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. (Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5)


There is only two differences, I checked the contained option on this AG [...]

When connecting to a contained AG, the contained master is used to authenticate the login. If you didn't add the login to the contained AG then you'll receive an error. This can easily be tested to see if you added it to the contained master or the instance/physical master by not using the listener but using the server name. If you can login using the server name, you added it to the instance master, which is incorrect.
